# How to get verbose output from custom powershell extension in Azure Devops

Tags: azure, powershell, logging, azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I have a custom extension for Azure Devops built in powershell. It works fine, however I'd like to get verbose output in logs from `New-AzResourceGroupDeployment`. No matter what I try - the output is hidden:

```
-Verbose with default $verbosePreference
-Verbose with $verbosePreference = "Continue"
-Verbose 4>&1 with default $verbosePreference
-Verbose 4>&1 with $verbosePreference = "Continue"
```

Locally it works fine. Any pointers?
ps. can't share extension code, unfortunately, but the relevant part is this:

```
$templateParameters = @{
    Verbose = $true
    xxx
}
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroup $rg @TemplateParameters 4>&1
```

EDIT: from what I can understand https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-task-lib/tree/master/powershell this library is rerouting the output. that can be reproduced locally with (after you import the library):

```
Invoke-VstsTastScript -ScriptBlock { Invoke-RestMethod -Method:post 'postman-echo.com/post' -Body 'test' -UseBasicParsing -Verbose }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I am unable to comment but wanted to suggest the use of `Out-String`.

```
$templateParameters = @{
    ResourceGroup = $rg
    Verbose = $true
}
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment @TemplateParameters 4>&1 | Out-String
```

What you're not showing is the actual output to the logs which could be the culprit.

Comment: you dont need out-string, anything that goes to stdout would appear in the logs. normally anyway, but i'll try this one

Comment: with `Out-String` (or `Out-Default` and `Out-Host`) it throws: `Index was outside the bounds of the array.`

Comment: okay, that was due to a call to bicep executable, this actually worked (whereas `Out-Host` or `Out-Default` didn't)